# Functors in separate files in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, functor

I want to have a big functor Hello(Blah: Blah_type) and save it in the file hello.ml, but how do I do this?

If I was just in my top level file, I'd have
    module Hello(Blah: Blah_type) =
      struct
        val x = 2
      end

but how do I put the argument in hello.ml? I can't just have the whole file being "val x = 2" ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible. Source files are always represented as ordinary modules, not functors. This is trivially solved with one extra open.

Answer (score 6):

OCamlPro has a compiler patch and external tool which may support this:

http://www.ocamlpro.com/blog/2011/08/10/ocaml-pack-functors.html

As far as I know the official compiler release does not support .ml files as functors.

Comment: The bigfunctor patch is useful when one wants to split a functor in several compilation units. It is however overkill here, where the matter is only of wrapping a functor as a module item of a single compilation unit.

Comment: I interpreted the question as looking for a way to avoid the Make in Hello.Make(...).  The patch and ocp-pack may be heavy approaches but as far as I know they are the only ones currently available.

Answer (score 5):

To complement ygrek's answer with a real code sample, instead of a file `foo.ml` with content

```
module type S = sig
  (* ... *)
end

module Hello (M : S) = struct
  (* ... *)
end

module M : S = struct
  (* ... *)
end

module H = Hello(M)

(* ... *)
```

You could have `hello.ml` with content

```
module type S = sig
  (* ... *)
end

module Make (M : S) = struct
  (* ... *)
end
```

and `foo.ml` rewritten as

```
module M : Hello.S = struct
  (* ... *)
end

module H = Hello.Make(M)

(* ... *)
```

PS: In case you find it confusing, the module sealing `M : S` or `M : Hello.S` is optional (M will be coerced to this signature when passed to the functor anyway), it was just to show how this can be done.